# Сохранение DataFrame в файл с разбивкой и количеством строк в наименовании файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame, например с таким содержанием:

[image: Пример DataFrame]

Задача разбить DataFrame по файлам, в которых будет заданное количество строк (задано в переменной) и файл остаток, если осталось не кратное содержимое.
Также каждый файл должен быть пронумерован порядковым номером сохранения.

В жизни файл имеет около 10 000 - 50 000 строк. Возможно это важно.
Если есть вариации по оптимизации - буду рад их увидеть ( например этот df будет содержать более 10 000 000 строк и бить по файлам в целях оптимизации ресурсов нужно будет как-то иначе.

По DataFame из примера (в df 5 строк) должны получиться такие файлы:

- sample_1_2.csv
- sample_2_2.csv
- sample_3_1.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(33, 3)), columns=list('abc'))

n = 10

(df.assign(x=np.arange(len(df)) // n)
   .groupby('x')
   .apply(lambda g: g.drop('x', 1)
                     .to_csv('d:/temp/file_{:03d}_{}.csv'
                             .format(g['x'].values[0], len(g)),
                             index=False)))
```

список получившихся файлов:

```
file_000_10.csv
file_001_10.csv
file_002_10.csv
file_003_3.csv
```

Comment: Добрый день @MaxU. Спасибо - действительно работает почти как надо.
На выходе получил три файла с порядковым номером, но за порядковым номером в имени должно следовать значение суммарного количества строк в  каждом файле. :-)

Comment: также я понимаю, что всё усложнится в том случае, если в решение от @MaxU добавить желание обработать файл (разбить) применяя выборку столбцов. Например я хочу сделать всё тоже самое, но с df['a']
Выскочит AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'assign'. Как в этом случае быть?

Comment: @APmansib, используйте `df[['a']]` - это вернет DataFrame с одним столбцом